# Aframe view local upload gltf file

Tags: javascript, vue.js, aframe, webvr

I've been trying to create a panel for creating and loading gltf models and viewing them on the fly in a-frame.

Currently the workflow is as following:

1. Using  tag to load from local storage.
2. Use v:on-change to assign the element.target.files[0] to a vue data tag.
3. Use v-bind to load the local gltf object to a  tag

However, I've noticed that the gltf loader can't receive a file object as it's input src, so I've try to do the following.

1. Open a FileReader
2. on data change, the FileReader will read it using readAsDataURL(data)
3. Assign the reader.result to the desired data tag.

Unfortunately, it is still not working, which says that the URI is malformed.

Lastly to my attempt, I've try to read it as a BinaryString, and bind it after JSON.stringify(binarystring) to src, but still not working.

Is there anyway a-frame accept a local file object as it's src?
If not, what's the best way to handle local file. It would be lot easier if I don't have to upload it into cloud storage first.

Thx for you patience!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that I don't need the filereader!

Just fix the url with URL.createObjectURL(object)
And everything is just fine.

However, I've noticed that if loading gltf file with reference file, it will not work. I have to embed all the files into the glb binary and load it.